# Submitting a form to a php script and returning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, contact-form

I have a contact form which initially `"onsubmit"` calls a javascript function to validate the content. If this function returns true it then posts the data to a php file.

At the end of this file I would like to return to the contact page, currently I am using this:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

is there a better way?

I would also like to change the css on an element on the contact page to display when I return (a thank you message), is this possible? I can set it to display using jQuery in the initial javascript function but that gets wiped out when it goes to the php file.

Thanks

Comment: Javascript runs Client Side, PHP runs Server Side. When you use the location tag it is sending you to a new PHP page, essentially reloading the contact page. This means any client side scripting that was executed after the first page load has been wiped out, and you are back to the original page load state.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that, which is why I'm hoping there is a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at Matt The Ninja's solution below. He is suggesting that you submit the form to PHP every time, then when you are in the PHP script you can validate and display the thank you, or fail validation and display an error about what went wrong, and you avoid the messy client side processing issues.

Answer (score 3):

Post to self then you if statement after post has been handled to redirect.
Do you redirect like you have said, using headers.

So make it post to self on the action part of your form

```
<form action="yourpage.php">
```

Then added PHP to handle post on yourpage.php

```
if(isset($_POST)){
 //Handle POSTed data.

 //if handled correctly
 {
  header("Location: somewhere.com")
 }
}
```

Comment: The advantage to this approach is that you would move your Javascript validation code to the PHP side, which is inherently more secure as it will run on the server, and not on the client where even an amateur web developer could screw with the code.

Comment: More secure yes, but this doesn't solve my issue with displaying a thank you message, and displaying errors from the php is more difficult. In Javascript I can just display errors straight onto the page. I have no doubt this is a better more secure way however.

Comment: You can still display a thank you message. Just display it as part of the if statement if data is posted correctly (or redirect to a thank you page). Displaying errors from php shouldn't be difficult see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: I'll have a look into it. I think you misunderstood what I meant by error, I mean user errors e.g. invalid email.

Comment: Ah sure, but you are handling these with JS before submitting the form right? You are only posting the form IF the validation is passed?

Comment: Correct, but from Marks comment I thought this was a replacement for that. I think what I'm going to do is just create a thank you page and re-direct it to that, seems like the simplest solution. Thanks

Comment: Certainly can redirect to a thank you page. Will work the same just means more changes. other IF (POST)[submit and show thank you]ELSE[show form] make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP_REFERER is not the best solution to accomplish a history -1 in PHP.

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) :

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, **it cannot really be trusted**.

The best solution is to explicitly write the page to return in the header function.

For the second question, you can redirect with a query parameter:

```
header('Location: script.php?valid=1');
```

And then test it in your view:

```
if (isset($_GET['valid']) && $_GET['valid'] == '1') {
     // display the message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the form submit the data to the same page of the contact form.
Then from the PHP script check if a form has been submitted, do your processing code and return a div with your thank you message.

Answer (score 0):

Say the name of your contact page was `index.php`. You could setup your form with the correct action (although it should be this way by default) and then check in the header for a submission parameter. Code below

```
<?php
  if (array_key_exists("submit_btn",$_REQUEST) {
    //display a thank you
  }
?>

<!-- more code here-->

<form action="index.php">
  <input name="whatever" type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="submit_btn">
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, how would I add a parameter to the header?

Comment: Well above, I'm just checking to see if the form was submitted by seeing if the `submit_btn` named element is available in the request. So that's what I mean by a submission parameter. Anytime the person submits the form, that parameter will be passed to the page on submission

Answer (score 0):

I found a few ways to do this in the end thanks to various peoples answers. Thanks all.

The simplest way was just to re-direct to a contact thank you page using the following header:

```
header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/contact-thankyou.html");
```

I changed to using SERVER_NAME as HTTP_REFERER wasn't a great solution.

The second solution, which was a bit uglier but did the job was to return to the same page with a header like this:

```
header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/contact.html?submitted");
```

Then use the following Javascript to detect the query parameter and change the css:

```
if (window.location.search.substring(1) == "submitted")
        {
            $("#message-sent").css({"display": "block"});
        }
```

This is NOT a great solution, as I'd prefer to get the query parameter using php but I'm restricted to html and Javascript on pages with the template system I'm having to build on.

Thanks all.